# I am building a chatbot in python. I am having trouble running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

```
import random
userKeywords = {"hi","hello","wassup","what'sup","greetings","sup","henlo","que onda","hola","hey","waddup"}

machineResponses = {"hello", "Hello there, I am a bot", "greetings from inside this computer"}

def machineAnswer(message):
    for key in userKeywords:
        if key == message:
            return random.choice(machineResponses)

def respondTo(message):
    print(machineAnswer(message))
respondTo("hello")
```

I am building a chatbot in python. I am having trouble running the code. My goal is to create a function that searches an array for a greeting keyword.If the keyword exists within the array, the bot responds with a similar response. For example, if user inputs "hello", the bot must recognize that hello is one of the greeting keywords and print out a similar string to "hello" as a response, by randomly choosing a response from "machineResponses". I have received the following errors:

```
print(machineAnswer(message))
File "C:\Users\gilbe\eclipse-workspace\python3.6\BeginnerFiles\ChatBot", line 9, in machineAnswer
return random.choice(machineResponses)

File "C:\Users\gilbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 259, in choice
return seq[i]

TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: PLEASE format your question with the proper indentation so it appears just like it does in your code. This is critical on this website so that we can easily read what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random.choice takes a random index from the object but you are using the set which doesn't support indexing, You can convert your set into a list and use it

> A set is just an unordered collection of unique elements. So, an
>   element is either in a set or it isn't. This means that no element in
>   a set has an index.

```
import random
userKeywords = {"hi","hello","wassup","what'sup","greetings","sup","henlo","que onda","hola","hey","waddup"}

machineResponses = ["hello", "Hello there, I am a bot", "greetings from inside this computer"]

def machineAnswer(message):
    for key in userKeywords:
        if key == message:
            return random.choice(machineResponses)

def respondTo(message):
    print(machineAnswer(message))
respondTo("hello")
```

Output:

```
Hello there, I am a bot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the iteration and check.
The problem with your statement was random.choice does not support set object.

```
import random
userKeywords = {"hi","hello","wassup","what'sup","greetings","sup","henlo","que onda","hola","hey","waddup"}

machineResponses = list({"hello", "Hello there, I am a bot", "greetings from inside this computer"})

def machineAnswer(message):
    if message in userKeywords:
        return random.choice(machineResponses)

def respondTo(message):
    print(machineAnswer(message))
respondTo("hello")
```

Comment: It definitely got rid of all the other errors, however, when I run it prompts another error. 

`if message in userKeywords:
        return random.choice(machineResponses)`

Answer (score 0):

## I'd try this:

```
import random
userKeywords = ["hi","hello","wassup","what'sup","greetings","sup","henlo","que onda","hola","hey","waddup"]

machineResponses = ["hello", "Hello there, I am a bot", "greetings from inside this computer"]

def machineAnswer(message):
    if message in userKeywords:
        return machineResponses[random.randint(0, 2)]

def respondTo(message):
    print(machineAnswer(message))
respondTo("hello")
```

## It worked when I tried it.